# Add correct value after nesting with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a project that has data of all countries in the world, years 2012 through 2018, nine commodity groups and both import and export. This is the data structure:

```
Countries,"Years","SITC","Commodity","Unit","Value"
Afghanistan,"2012","0 Food and livestock","Import","mln euro","1"
Afghanistan,"2012","0 Food and livestock","Export","mln euro","20"
Afghanistan,"2012","1 Alcohol and tobacco","Import","mln euro","0"
Afghanistan,"2012","1 Alcohol and tobacco","Export","mln euro","5"
Afghanistan,"2012","2 Non-edible raw material","Import","mln euro","."
Afghanistan,"2012","2 Non-edible raw material","Export","mln euro","0"
```

After writing a d3 nest that looks like this:

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
    .key(function (d) {
        return d.Countries;
    })
    .key(function (d) {
        return d.Years;
    })
    .key(function (d) {
        return d.SITC;
    })
    .key(function (d) {
        return d.Commodity;
    })
    .rollup(function (d) {
        return d.Value;
    })
    .entries(data);
console.log(nested_data)
```

this is the result in the console.

[image]

How do I give the "Import" and "Export" the values from the dataset? I can't seem to figure it out.

Edit: I renamed the names in the code for this question. That's why the output screenshot is different.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the sum function into your rollup. The 'leaves' corresponding to the group are the argument to the rollup function. So something like this should work:

```
.rollup(function (leaves) {
        return d3.sum(leaves, function(d) { return +d.Value });
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't understand what you mean with 'leaves'. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: The leaves are the elements that have been grouped by the keys i.e. the elements that sit together in a particular group. The first argument to the rollup function is that array of elements that sit within a group. So, in your example, leaves will be an array of elements that has the same country, year, SITC, and commodity.